# How to change size of replace dialog box of pluma text editor

Tags: gedit, resize, dialog, pluma

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 Mate LTS (and I know there is a newer version).

The size of the replace dialog of the Pluma (v. 1.24.0) editor seems to be fixed. I'd like to enlarge it so that I can see complete strings in the search and the replace box even when they are very long. Is that possible?

I also have gedit 3.36.2 installed where that dialog box is resizeable. But gedit seems to lack other features which I prefer, like "show ALL characters (spaces, line breaks...)".

Comment: gedit: see the draw-spaces plugin for that 1 issue you have with it.

Comment: As for Pluma that is something to bring up with the developers of that app.